# How does Memory Controller distributes the data to DIMMs?

Tags: memory, cpu, ram

A hypothetical scenario is when a computer has 2 dimms, how do the memory controller distributes the data between the two?

It has to use some bits from the address, but which bits and why those bits.

I would say per dimm bank/row size make some sense, since we would have a big number of concurrently valid rowbuffers and may increase bandwidth.

How is it actually done? (Let's assume a common CPU architecture on x86)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://lackingrhoticity.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/how-physical-addresses-map-to-rows-and-banks.html) he presents some results based on his experiments for Intel Sandy Bridge CPUs:

> Bits 0-5: These are the lower 6 bits of the byte index within a row (i.e. the 6-bit index into a 64-byte cache line).
>
> Bit 6: This is a 1-bit channel number, which selects between the 2 DIMMs.
>
> Bits 7-13: These are the upper 7 bits of the index within a row (i.e. the upper bits of the column number).
>   Bits 14-16: These are XOR'd with the bottom 3 bits of the row number to give the 3-bit bank number.
>
> Bit 17: This is a 1-bit rank number, which selects between the 2 ranks of a DIMM (which are typically the two sides of the DIMM's circuit board).
>
> Bits 18-32: These are the 15-bit row number.
>
> Bits 33+: These may be set because physical memory starts at physical addresses greater than 0.